# Why c++ code implementation is not performing better than the python implementation?

Tags: python, c++, performance

I am doing benchmarking for finding nearest neighbour for the datapoints. My c++ implementation and python implementation are taking almost same execution time. Shouldn't be c++ works better than the raw python implementation.

- C++ Execution Time    : 8.506 seconds
- Python Execution Time : 8.7202 seconds

### C++ Code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>     // std::iota

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

double edist(double* arr1, double* arr2, uint n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += pow(arr1[i] - arr2[i], 2);
    }
    return sqrt(sum); }

template <typename T> vector<size_t> argsort(const vector<T> &v) {
  // initialize original index locations
  vector<size_t> idx(v.size());   iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](size_t i1, size_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

  return std::vector<size_t>(idx.begin() + 1, idx.end()); }

int main() {

    uint N, M;
    // cin >> N >> M;
    N = 1000;
    M = 800;
    double **arr = new double*[N];
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distr(10.0, 60.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = new double[M];
        for(int j=0; j < M; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = distr(eng);
        }
    }
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    map<int, vector<size_t> > dist;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        vector<double> distances;
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            distances.push_back(edist(arr[i], arr[j], N));
        }
        dist[i] = argsort(distances);
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start);
    int dur = duration.count();
    cout<<"Time taken by code: "<<dur<<" microseconds"<<endl;
    cout<<" In seconds: "<<dur/pow(10,6);  
        return 0; }
```

### Python Code:

```python
import time
import numpy as np
def comp_inner_raw(i, x):
    res = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=np.float64)
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((i-x[j])**2))
    return res
def nearest_ngbr_raw(x): # x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    #print("My array: ",x)
    dist = {}
    for idx,i in enumerate(x):
        #lst = []
        lst = comp_inner_raw(i,x)
        s = np.argsort(lst)#[1:]
        sorted_array = np.array(x)[s][1:]
        dist[idx] = s[1:]
    return dist
arr = np.random.rand(1000, 800)
start = time.time()
table = nearest_ngbr_raw(arr)
print("Time taken to execute the code using raw python is {}".format(time.time()-start))
```

### Compile Command:

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 knn.cpp -o knn
> ```

C++ compiler(g++) version for ubuntu 18.04.1: **7.4.0**

Coded in **c++11**

**Numpy version** : 1.16.2

**Edit**
Tried with compiler optimization, now it is taking around 1 second.
Can this c++ code be optimized further from coding or any other perspective?

Comment: No optimization question is complete without providing toolchain spec and full compile command.

Comment: I have just executed both codes on my machine (g++-9 and python3). The C++ program takes about 1 second, whereas python script 10 seconds. You are probably missing something (e.g., compiler optimizations)

Comment: try `g++ -std=c++11 knn.cpp -o -O3 knn`

Comment: After your edit, I can definitely say you are missing compiler optimizations. By default, `gcc` does not enable optimizations. You should pass proper flags to your compiler (in accordance with your context and platform). For instance, `-O3 -march=native`. [Here a list of flags on GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Not working for my g++ version.

Comment: @Pygirl Be sure you are issuing the correct comand (i.e., `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -o knn knn.cpp`)

Comment: To get your code correct, build without optimizations (since it compiles faster and its runtime speed is irrelevant), but for timing tests you should let the compiler optimize either with -O2 or -O3 (which build slower but the result runs faster.)  Telling the compiler the platform to compile for (-march=....) can also help it generate code using better instructions your machine offers that may not necessarily be available in the generic instruction set it otherwise targets by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this c++ code be optimized further from coding or any other perspective?

I can see at least three optimisations. The first two are easy and should definitely be done but in my testing they end up not impacting the runtime measurably. The third one requires rethinking the code minimally.

1. `edist` caculates a costly square root, but you are only using the distance for pairwise comparison. Since the square root function is monotonically increasing, it has no impact on the comparison result. Similarly, `pow(x, 2)` can be replaced with `x * x` and this is sometimes faster:

   ```cpp
   double edist(std::vector<double> const& arr1, std::vector<double> const& arr2, uint n) {
       double sum = 0.0;
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           auto const diff = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
           sum += diff * diff;
       }
       return sum;
   }
   ```
2. `argsort` performs a copy because it returns the indices excluding the first element. If you instead include the first element (change the return statement to `return idx;`), you avoid a potentially costly copy.
3. Your matrix is represented as a nested array (and you’re for some reason using raw pointers instead of a nested `std::vector`). It’s generally more efficient to represent matrices as contiguous N*M arrays: `std::vector<double> arr(N * M);`. This is also how numpy represents matrices internally. This requires changing the code to calculate the indices.

Comment: Bonus for extra points: The last suggestion actually makes the code minimally *slower*, not faster. Explain why and suggest a way to fix this.